# How to get an Array of an Object inside of an array? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

atm I'm trying to code a rubics cube but I can't get it working.
So I got my class which is called "littlecube". It got an array of it's vertices(4 per side * 6 sides).The array is already filled with the right values. So I imagine each cube of the rubics cube as an object with 24 vertices. Is there another way to declare the three floats in the cpp file? Thought of the cubes as objects. Like in java or c#.To be honest I'm a big noob in C++.

littleCube.h:

```
#pragma once
class littleCube
{   
public:
    littleCube(void);
    littleCube(const int positionX,const int positionY,const int positionZ);
    ~littleCube(void);

    void calculateVertices(void);
    void rotateVertical(const float rotationAngle);
    void rotateHorizontal(const float rotationAngle);
    void printLittleCube(void);
    void printPosition(void);
    void printRotation(void);
    void printVertices(void);
    float* getMyVertices(void);
};
```

littleCube.cpp:

```
#include "littleCube.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

//Position of each Cube
float f_myPosition[4];
//Rotation of each Cube
float f_myRotation[4][4];
//All Vertices of a cube
float f_myVertices[24][3];

using namespace std;

//default constructor
littleCube::littleCube(void)
{
}

float* littleCube::getMyVertices(void)
{
    return &f_myVertices[0][0];
}
```

After that I made an array of littleCubes which is 3 dimensional and I want to access each cubes field of vertices.

```
#include "littleCube.h"

typedef struct BasicVertex
{
    float position[3];
    uint32_t color;
} BasicVertex;

static BasicVertex  *s_basicVertices= NULL;
littleCube bigCube[3][3][3];

int main( void )
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
   {
       for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
       {
           for(int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
           {
               bigCube[x][y][z] = littleCube::littleCube(x+1,y+1,z+1);
           }
       }
   }
   createGmxData();
}
```

So in the following Code I'm getting an error at the following line:
"s_basicVertices[i].position[0] = &pointer[cubeVertices][0];"

```
void createGxmData( void )
{
    s_basicVertices = (BasicVertex *)graphicsAlloc( ..., numVertices * 6 *sizeof(BasicVertex), 4, ..., ...);

    int x,y,z,i = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        float* pointer = bigCube[x][y][z].getMyVertices();
        for(int cubeVertices = 0; cubeVertices < 24; cubeVertices++)
        {
            s_basicVertices[i].position[0] = &pointer[cubeVertices][0]; //x
            s_basicVertices[i].position[1] = &pointer[cubeVertices][1]; //y
            s_basicVertices[i].position[2] = &pointer[cubeVertices][2]; //z
            i++;
        }
        z++;
            if(z == 3)
            {
                z = 0;
                y++;
                if( y == 3)
                {
                    y = 0;
                    x++;
                    if( x == 3)
                        break;
                }
            }

    }
}
```

The Problem I get now is "error 143: expression must have pointer-to-object type" and I don't know why. Thought I got a pointer to the f_myVertices of each cube now.

The reason why I'm not showing the whole code is that it's the development kit for the psVita and I'm not shure if I'm allowed to show the code.

Many thanks 
Ben

Comment: which line is having errors? Where is `s_basicVertices` declared? Are `f_myVertices` a part of `littleCube`? You aren't showing the declaration of `littleCube` at the moment. Why are those three floats declared in the .cpp file?